# Can I post a message to a window.opener

Tags: javascript

I am doing `window.opener.postMessage('a=1','*')` where the current window was opened via `window.open`.

A `console.log` of `window.opener` does show the right window but I do not see messages coming into the opener.

I am doing `$(window).on( 'message', handleMessage );` where handleMessage has a `console.log` to know it was hit. I have done this several times for cross-iframe communication, and was hoping to achieve the same thing for my new window.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue here is the `jQuery` event handler. `postMessage` natively will work like this

```
function handleMessage( evt ) {
  // evt.data will be whatever was posted
}

window.addEventListener( "message", handleMessage, false );
```

jQuery does this:

```
function handleMessage( evt ) {
  // evt.data will be from jQuery where it populates from an argument in .trigger
  // evt.originalEvent.data is from the postMessage
}
$(window).on( 'message', handleMessage );
```

Browser compatibility should also be noted from the previous answer ( which I'm upvoting ), however the case here in Firefox/Chrome is what I've written.

Answer (score 2):

From [caniuse](http://caniuse.com/#search=postMessage):

> Partial support in IE8-9 refers to only working in frames/iframes (not other tabs/windows).

So  yes, you can, but browser support is more limited.

Comment: Thanks, having some trouble in FF too... seeing if that's my fault or not and then I can accept this